# OWL Class Expression Syntax Minimum and Maximum Cardinality for Object Properties

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege

I am currently trying to model an ontology in Protégé. In the [documentation](http://protegeproject.github.io/protege/class-expression-syntax/) I can find all kind of class expressions but is there a way of defining a minimum cardinality AND a maximum cardinality at the same time?

If this is not possible, could you tell my why this is the case?

Comment: `min` and `max` on the same relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create two cardinalities on different relations, there is no problem :

```
(Owner owns min 2 Cats) and (Owner owns max 3 Dogs)
```

And it is also possible for only one relation :

```
(Owner owns min 2 Cats) and (Owner owns max 3 Cats)
```

Just be sure that the values are logic ( `min < max` )and be careful about Inclusive and Exclusive conditions on Cardinalities.

This can be done in the "Class Expression Editor".

Comment: Thank you. After some playing around I found out that you have to use the 'Class Expression Editor' in Protégé and write it in there by hand rather than using the 'Object Restriction Creator'.

Comment: With a bit of training and experiments, you will only use the Class Expression Editor :D